# How to avoid date-picker displaying default date (12/31/1969)?

Tags: yii

I've tried `defaultDate=""` property but it doesn't show even if I gave some value to the date picker?

Here's my datepicker code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'date_healed',
    'value'=>$date_healed,
    'name'=>'date_healed'.$i,
    // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
    'options'=>array(
        //'autoSize'=>true,
        'defaultDate'=>"",                              
        'changeMonth'=>'true', 
        'changeYear'=>'true', 
        'yearRange'=>Yii::app()->params['YearRange'], 
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>'10')
));
```

Comment: I think, this value will be from  $model->date_healed .

Comment: No SuVeRa, if I don't give any value it provides 12/31/1969 else it provides correct value. I tried defaultDate="", after that even if I gave some value still it provides "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you delete default value from database table

if you see the table structure ...  if you see like this, then remove '0000-00-00'

```
....
`date_healed` date NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
....
```

should be...

```
....
`date_healed` date NULL,
....
```

Comment: Yes SuVera, the table stores the value as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: But I'm not able to make the default value as NULL in the table. it display error    #1067 - Invalid default value for 'date_healed'

Comment: run this sql `ALTER TABLE  your_table CHANGE  date_healed  date_healed DATETIME NULL;`  or to make it not null run this ... `ALTER TABLE  your_table CHANGE  date_healed  date_healed DATETIME NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks SuVera, The Table altered as NULL as default value, but still can't get the output still it display's nothing even if I gave some value to date_healed field.

Comment: if ($site[$j]['date_healed'] == "")
$date_healed = "";

Comment: It worked after I insert the above line. ($site[$j]['date_healed'] == "") place where I get value for the date_healed and the variable $date_healed is the value of the date_picker